# Array Compatiblilty java

Tags: java, arrays

These are my instructions:

> Two arrays are said to be compatible if they are of the same size and
>   if the ith element in the first array is greater than or equal to the
>   ith element in the second array for all elements. If the array size is
>   zero or less then display the message "Invalid array size". Write a Java
>   program to find whether 2 arrays are compatible or not. If the arrays
>   are compatible display the message as "Arrays are Compatible", if not
>   then display the message as "Arrays are Not Compatible".

**My solution is as follows:**

```java
class CompaibleArrays {
    public static void main(String []args){
        int n1=0;
        int n2=0;
        int flag=0;
        int []a1 = new int[20];
        int []a2 = new int[20];
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the size for First array:");
        n1 = sc.nextInt();
        if(n1<1){
            System.out.println("Invalid array size");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Enter the elements for First array:");
            for(int i=0 ; i<n1 ; i++){
                a1[i] = sc.nextInt();
            }

            System.out.println("Enter the size for Second array:");
            n2 = sc.nextInt();
            if(n1<1){
                System.out.println("Invalid array size");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Enter the elements for Second array:");
                for(int j=0 ; j<n2 ; j++){
                    a2[j] = sc.nextInt();
                }
            }
        }
        if(n1==n2){
            System.out.println("Arrays are Not Compatible");
        }
        else{
            for(int x=0 ; x<n1 ; x++){
                if(a1[x]>=a2[x]){
                    flag++;
                }
            }
            if(flag==n1){
                System.out.println("Arrays are Compatible");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Arrays are Not Compatible");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

#### Sample Input 1 :

```
 Enter the size for First array:
 5
 Enter the elements for First array:
 5
 14
 17
 19
 15
 Enter the size for Second array:
 5
 Enter the elements for Second array:
 2
 5
 9
 15
 7
 Sample Output 1:
 Arrays are Compatible
```

#### Sample Input 2 :

```
 Enter the size for First array:
 3
 Enter the elements for First array:
 1
 4
 7
 Enter the size for Second array:
 5
 Enter the elements for Second array:
 2
 5
 9
 5
 7
 Sample Output 2:
 Arrays are Not Compatible
```

#### Sample Input 3 :

```
 Enter the size for First array:
 -2
 Sample Output 3:
 Invalid array size
```

** Help me out **

Comment: Replace if(n1==n2) with if(n1 != n2)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues in your code.

1. In your else block, you need to replace `(n1<1)` with `(n2<1)`.
2. Replace `if(n1==n2)` with `if(n1!=n2)`
3. You do not need to iterate through all the elements. If at any point you find the index elements of both the arrays do not satisfy the condition, you should break the loop. Use a boolean flag for this.

> ```
> public class CompaibleArrays {
>     public static void main(String []args){
>         int n1=0;
>         int n2=0;
>         boolean flag=true;
>         int []a1 = new int[20];
>         int []a2 = new int[20];
>         Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
>
>         System.out.println("Enter the size for First array:");
>         n1 = sc.nextInt();
>         if(n1<1){
>             System.out.println("Invalid array size");
>         }
>         else{
>             System.out.println("Enter the elements for First array:");
>             for(int i=0 ; i<n1 ; i++){
>                 a1[i] = sc.nextInt();
>             }
>
>             System.out.println("Enter the size for Second array:");
>             n2 = sc.nextInt();
>             if(n2<1){
>                 System.out.println("Invalid array size");
>             }
>             else{
>                 System.out.println("Enter the elements for Second array:");
>                 for(int j=0 ; j<n2 ; j++){
>                     a2[j] = sc.nextInt();
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>         if(n1!=n2){
>             System.out.println("Arrays are Not Compatible");
>         }
>         else{
>             for(int x=0 ; x<n1 ; x++){
>                 if(a1[x]<a2[x]){
>                     flag = false;
>                     break;
>                 }
>             }
>             if(flag==true){
>                 System.out.println("Arrays are Compatible");
>             }
>             else{
>                 System.out.println("Arrays are Not Compatible");
>             }
>         }
>
>     }
> }
> ```